# Trying to suppress StyleCop message SA1513:ClosingCurlyBracketMustBeFollowedByBlankLine

Tags: c#, stylecop

I am trying to suppress the following StyleCop message for a specific property:

```
SA1513: Statements or elements wrapped in curly brackets must be followed by a blank line.
```

I am trying to do the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1513:ClosingCurlyBracketMustBeFollowedByBlankLine", Justification = "There are no issues with this code")]
    public string CustomerId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty(CustomerIdProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.IsNew)
            {
                this.SetProperty(CustomerIdProperty, value);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ReadOnlyException("Id value can only be changed for a new record.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I just doing something wrong? Or is this just not possible? It's a good rule, just not valid in my case for a property.

**Update**

Tried switching from DocumentationRules to LayoutRules ... still not suppressing.

```
    [DataObjectField(true, false)]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules", "SA1513:ClosingCurlyBracketMustBeFollowedByBlankLine", Justification = "There are no issues with this code")]
    public string CustomerId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetProperty(CustomerIdProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.IsNew)
            {
                this.SetProperty(CustomerIdProperty, value);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ReadOnlyException("Id value can only be changed for a new record.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be a problem with StyleCop. Which version do you have installed? [This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/archive/2009/08/10/rule-suppressions.aspx) states that:

> Starting with StyleCop 4.3.2, it is possible to suppress the reporting of rule violations by adding suppression attributes within the source code.

I've just found that I can't suppress any messages. The installer I used just gives the version as 4.3. The latest version on the [Codeplex](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) is 4.4.0.0. Make sure you have that version installed.

**Update**

I've been doing some checking and I can suppress DocumentationRules:

```
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules",
                     "SA1600:ElementsMustBeDocumented",
                     Justification = "Reviewed. Suppression is OK here.")]
```

but not SpacingRules or LayoutRules. However, nothing I've found indicates why this should be the case.

Comment: I think it might be a bug ... trying to suppress that message still gives the warning.

Comment: I agree with ChrisF's assessment - even in 4.4, SpacingRules and LayoutRules do not appear to be suppressable.

Comment: You need to remove the `Microsoft.` prefix in the category when using stylecop 4.7.

Answer (score 3):

Your suppression uses `Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules`. I think it should be `Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules`.

Comment: That makes sense ... made the change but still not suppressing.

Answer (score 3):

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules", "SA1513:ClosingCurlyBracketMustBeFollowedByBlankLine", Justification = "There are no issues with this code")]
```

works in latest StyleCop. Just removed "Microsoft." prefix.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in StyleCop that let's you only suppress certain kinds of rules. This will be fixed in StyleCop 4.4, which is due to be released soon.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful to read the StyleCop documentation to figure-out how to suppress a rule.  The following worked in my code:

```
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules",
    "SA1402:FileMayOnlyContainASingleClass",
    Justification = "Splitting this file into classes would get too confusing.")]
```

From the help file:

> The SuppressMessage attribute has the following format:
>
> [SuppressMessage("Rule Category, "Rule Id", "Justification")]
>
> Where:
>
> - **Rule Category** - The StyleCop rule namespace in which the rule is defined. For example,
>     Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules
> - **Rule Id** -The identifier for the rule, using the format shortname:longname.
>
>   For example, SA1600:ElementsMustBeDocumented
> - **Justification** - The text that is used to document the reason for suppressing
>     the message.

And as already mentioned, make sure you are referencing the correct rules namespace.

Answer (score -2):

Just put a blank line between your get block and your set block.
That's all you have to do, add one blank line and the problem is solved.

Comment: -1 This post doesn't answer OP's question. He asked how to disable that rule, not how to comply with it.